# CSS | How to keep floating from making element fill 100% height?

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical menu. Each li has a `<a>` link which is floated left, and on the same line I have another `<a>` that is floated right. It floats correctly, but I want the second `<a>` to be a button, so I try to set the width/height and background color. When I set the width/height, it doesn't work. I have tried setting inline-block, and the height still takes up 100% of the li. The li height is set to 50px btw. Thank you, if there is additional info that you need, then please ask.

HTML

```
<li class="search_items"> /* An li of the nav */
<form>
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search Items...">
</form>
<div class="results" style="display:none">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class='item_name' href='itemDetail.php'></a>
            <a class='item_category' href='categoryDetail.php'></a>
            <a class='addItem'>AddItem</a> /* addItem is an <a> that I style as a button */
        </li> 

    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.navbar li.search_items input { /* Item search text input */
width: 500px;
height: 40px;
text-indent: 10px;
font-size: 20px;
top: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
outline: none;
border: none;
}

div.navbar li.search_items div.results {
background-color: white;
width: 500px;
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
border-top: none;
max-height: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
}

div.navbar li.search_items div.results ul {
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

div.navbar li.search_items div.results ul li {
background-color: white;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
line-height: 50px;
position: relative;
}

div.navbar li.search_items div.results ul li a.item_name {
float: left;
}

div.navbar li.search_items div.results ul li a.item_category {
    float: left;
}

div.navbar li.search_items div.results ul li a.addItem{
display: inline-block;
float: right;
}
```

All of the code is mainly for a real time quick search. As the user types, below the textbox are the results of the products.

Comment: You'll likely get a better answer if you post your CSS/html

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle, codepen, or code you could post?

Comment: add display:block or display:inline-block to a tag

Comment: Please write a [mcve]

Comment: @KScandrett I am posting code, thanks for your response

Comment: @AllDani Code added

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what do you mean?